# Forward Stepwise selection

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, model-selection, least-squares, regularization

I am assuming the following model:

$Y = \beta X + \epsilon$

Here both $X$ and $Y$ are matrices. I fit the least squares model without any regularization and get the matrix $\beta$. I would like to do the following now. I want to pick some subset $S$ of rows of $\beta$ using forward stepwise selection such that these rows minimize the squared loss. How should one go about it?

Comment: It's probably best to *avoid* going about it. If that doesn't make sense / you want to understand why, it may help to read my answer here: [algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836//20856#20856). Why are you opposed to regularization?

Comment: I am not opposed to regularization. Its just that I was not planning to use it for the case now.